# Parse XML NaN Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, nan

i got this code with JS, parsing from XML, my Output displays NaN in Chrome, FF, IE... and I don't know why, wether where it comes from. All my XML fields are Chars, thats why i use .text() function...

```
    function parse(document){
    $(document).find("EMaDetails").each(function(){
        $("#main").append(
            '<table>'
            +'<tr>'+'<td>'
            +$(this).find('Nachn').text()+', '
            +$(this).find('Vorna').text()
            +'</td>'+'</tr>'+
            +'<tr>'+'<td>'
            +$(this).find('Detail1').text()+', '
            +$(this).find('Detail2').text()
            +'</td>'+'</tr>'
            +'</table>'
            );


    });
}
```

And the Result is like this:

```
NaN
Lastname1, Firstname1
Detail1, Detaila1
NaN
Lastname2, Firstname2
Detail2, Detaila2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+'</td>'+'</tr>'+
```

remove the + at the and of this line(the next line starts with a + too)

Comment: No(it's not really an error), but maybe you can use jquery-templates to avoid those errors.

Answer (score 0):

(This not an not answer but more of a comment, however I needed more space and the formatting of an answer to show my point.)

The best way to avoid this kind of error is to consistently use a code convention on how to format your code. There are [many suggestions for code conventions](http://www.google.de/search?q=java%20script%20code%20convention) around, but it's not important which one you use, as long you are comfortable with it and most importantly use it consistently.

In you case, where you are wrapping a long expression over several lines, there are three thing you should look out for:

- Ident the following lines
- Use spaces before and after a binary operator
- And most importantly place the operators consistently either at the start or the end of the line. (Don't go mixing the placement, or you'll get errors like you did.)

Personnally I like to have the operator at the end of the line, so you "know" that the line has to continue, and there is less danger to confuse the binary `+` with a unary `+` as it happened in your case.

```
'<table>' +
  '<tr>' + '<td>' +
  $(this).find('Nachn').text() + ', ' +
  $(this).find('Vorna').text() +
  '</td>' + '</tr>' +
  '<tr>' + '<td>' +
  $(this).find('Detail1').text() + ', '  +
  $(this).find('Detail2').text()  +
  '</td>' + '</tr>' +
  '</table>'
```